# Mocha + Mongoose - Timeout of X exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

## Introduction

I have a simple method get an X number of rows from my mongoose database. I am trying to test this method using Mocha.

Here is the method:

```
public async findManyByCount (amount: number) {
  const profiles: any = await Document.find({}).sort({'date': -1}).limit(amount)
  return profiles
}
```

Here is my test:

```
describe.only('`findManyByCount`', function () {
  this.timeout(10000)
  it('Should return the number of profiles specified', async function () {
    const Profile = new ProfileModel
    const count = 5
    const profiles = await Profile.findManyByCount(count)
    expect(profiles.length).to.equal(count)   
  })
})
```

## Problem

I am getting the following error when i run the test:

```
Profile Model
  Methods
    `findManyByCount`
      1) Should return the number of profiles specified
      - Should fail if no count is specified


  0 passing (10s)
  1 pending
  1 failing

  1) Profile Model
       Methods
         `findManyByCount`
           Should return the number of profiles specified:
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/var/www/api/tests/models/ProfileModel.js)
```

I have solved this type of error message before but not matter what I do, i cant seem to fix it.

I should also **note** I can run the mongoose query fine in a shell and it also runs fine in my website. I should also **confirm** the query is whats hanging - nothing after the `await ....` runs

## Things I've Tried

I've tried increasing/decreasing the timeout

Reducing the query to a simple `.find({})`

Try/catch block

## The Question

What would be causing this issue? Like i said, my web app runs the query fine (makes a call to the method on the landing page), and i can run the query in a shell with instant results

## Edit

What I've found is, this is the case for many queries when running mocha tests. I am definitely connected to the database as well - i'm not sure how to debug it anymore to figure out the problem?

Comment: Did you verify that the mongoose instance is connected to the DB?

Comment: Omg.. it wasn't for some reason. Connected and now it works fine. Can't believe I missed such a tiny thing! Thanks :)